# Object.Assign not creating new instances

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, redux, mapping

I have the following code, building an action payload for Redux:

```
  export function getInfoFromAPI() {
  const initialAction = {
    type: types.GET_SETTLE_SHEETS_FROM_LOCAL_API
  };
  let returnedAction = {};
  let payloadBuild = {};
  return dispatch => {
    return APItools.getInfoFromLocalAPI()
      .then(jsonResult => {
        Object.keys(jsonResult).map( (resultArrayId) => {
          debugger;
          const { foo, bar, foobar, foofoo, barbar} = jsonResult[resultArrayId];
          payloadBuild = _.merge({}, 
            {
              [barbar]: {
                foo: foo,
                bar: bar,
                foobar: foobar,
                foofoo: foofoo,
                barbar: barbar
              }
            });
        });
        returnedAction = Object.assign({}, initialAction,
          {
            payload: payloadBuild
          });
        dispatch(returnedAction);
      });
  };
}
```

I'm trying to build a single json object that will encompass the data coming in from my local API. When I've used Object.assign() before, it would work add information based on the key, and append it to a pre-existing object, the way you would think it would.

I've tried the lodash _.merge(), and Object.assign both, switching them around and it doesn't seem to be working... it keeps overwriting the key [barbar] with the next value coming in from the map function, even though it'd be like

```
[barbar] = 1
```

then

```
[barbar] = 2
```

It will replace the key and all of it's children.... why? And also how do I fix this? When I've used Object.assign before, it would just append the new keys to the object, but it was only ever one at a time I think. This is the first time I'm using map, which I would assume would just continue to append new objects with their unique key values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting to merge in your old values

```
let buildValue = {}

arrayWithStuff.map(info => {
  buildValue = Object.assign(buildValue, {
    [info.bar] : {
      Other stuff..
    })
```

You are merging each result with a new empty object (first argument).

Good luck!

Comment: Yep! I just found that as you posted :-) thank you. I'll mark yours as the answer though to give you them points! :)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```
payloadBuild = _.merge({}, payloadBuild <---- this needed to be added
            {
              [barbar]: {
                foo: foo,
                bar: bar,
                foobar: foobar,
                foofoo: foofoo,
                barbar: barbar
              }
            });
```